# GWT + SmartGWT + Javascript: external script integration

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt

I am building a web application using GWT and SMartGWT and I need to integrate an external script for a Photo Gallery: http://slideshow.triptracker.net/.
My current attempt is:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://slideshow.triptracker.net/slide.js").setCallback(
              new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
                     public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
                       Window.alert("Script load failed.");
                     }
                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                      Window.alert("Script load success.");
                     }
                  }).inject();
```

Afterwards, I call this method:

Code:

```
native static void example(String p) /*-{

     $wnd.viewer = new $wnd.PhotoViewer();
             $wnd.viewer.add(p)
     $wnd.viewer.show(0);

}-*/;
```

This does not give any error, but the photogallery appears **BEHIND** my Entry Point Layout, so it's not possible to use it.

So, I am trying to find a workaround and I would like to refer to the main layout from Javasript, to run the script on that. Is this possible? I've tried with

```
 foo.getElement().getId();
```

but it returns me something like

```
 isc_VLayout_0_wrapper
```

However, Javascript doesn't like it.

Then I tried

```
  foo.getDOM.getId();

  isc_1
```

But the result doesn't change.

Can someone help me fix this issue?
Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean with behind? It is in thee DOM, but with the wrong z-index? In this case, everything regarding the scriptinjection works fine. I think you need to show some of your layout code.

Comment: I mean that it is in the background, placed on the "layer behind" the rest of the page, which makes it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I think here are two things, that are possibly wrong:

1. You have an `onSuccess()` callback you can call the `jsni` call from within.

   ```
   //1
   ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://slideshow.triptracker.net/slide.js").setCallback(
       new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
           public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
               //3a
           }
           public void onSuccess(Void result) {
               example("works"); 
               //3b                 
           }
       }).inject();
   //2
   example("not loaded");
   ```
2. You may also try to call `.setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)` before calling `.inject()`

Comment: 1) I am invoking the native method on the button click, after the script has been injected. 2) Tried, it doesn't work (nothing changed unfortunately)